# R programming Data Manipulation

Tags: r

[image]

I have a data with millions of rows.
i want to do some data manipulations in R.

The below image describes the conditions.
I want final result stored in Result variable.
Here NA means not applicable for this logic.

Outputdata is my final dataset.
Create a new variable Result and insert values according to below conditions.

Case 1:
If Lost = 1 and PPP >= 0.8 then Result = PPP
Case 2:
If Lost = 1 and PPP < 0.8 then Result = 0.935294

Also, if Result is non blank then apply Case 2 for those rows.
If Result has a value due to previous cases don't over write the value.

Please help me. R is very new for me.

Comment: Please read about how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If `df` stores your data frame just do (with `dplyr` package):

```
df %>% mutate(Result=ifelse( Lost==1 & PPP >=0.8, as.character(PPP), ifelse(Lost==1 & PPP<0.8,0.935294,NA ))
```